# Products combining framework and visual IDE for web development?

Tags: ide, frameworks, rad

We are looking for some tools to help us with our web development speed.

The two main areas that we have pinpointed as parts of the problem are "Framework/Flow Management" and "Visual/Layout Development"

Ideally we would find a tool that handles both rather well.  However, it seems like there are few tools that handle the middle ground well. Usually it is just a Framework, or and IDE, not both.  The best thing we have found so far is Agile Platform.

Are we missing any obvious products?

Platform at this point is not a huge concern.  We can migrate to the best tool.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Visual Studio 2008/2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/vstudio/default.aspx). Framework would be [ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.Net MVC](http://asp.net).